# I need to print 5 ducks Horizontally, but nothing works

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, printing

I need to print 5 ducks in a horizontal line using only for loops and static methods. I got to this so far but the ducks shift.

````
 public static void main(String[] args) {
       int numDucks = 5;
       printHat(numDucks);
       printBody(numDucks);
       printWater(numDucks);
   }

public static void printHat(int numDucks) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= numDucks; i++) {
        System.out.print("               ____       ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numDucks; i++) {
        System.out.print("            __|____|__    ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numDucks; i++) {
        System.out.print("           |__________|   ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void printBody(int numDucks) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= numDucks; i++) {
        System.out.print("            ((      ))   ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numDucks; i++) {
        System.out.print("           ((     O  ```)\"");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numDucks; i++) {
        System.out.print("           ((        ``)   ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numDucks; i++) {
        System.out.print("            \\\\     x``   ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numDucks; i++) {
        System.out.print("     (())    \\\\     X   ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numDucks; i++) {
        System.out.print("    ((  ))~~~~      ))   ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numDucks; i++) {
        System.out.print("  ((                 ))   ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numDucks; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ((      ~~~~~~       ))   ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numDucks; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ((     ~~~~~~~~      ))   ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numDucks; i++) {
        System.out.print("  \\\\     ~~~~~~      //   ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void printWater(int numDucks) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= numDucks; i++) {
        System.out.print("   --__--__--__--__--__   ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numDucks; i++) {
        System.out.print("  --__--__--__--__--__   ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    }
  }
````

This is what I should get (but 5 times horizontally):

````
              ____           
           __|____|__         
          |__________|       
           ((      ))
          ((     O  ```)
          ((        ``) 
           \\     x``
    (())    \\     X
   ((  ))~~~~      ))
 ((                 ))
((      ~~~~~~       ))   
((     ~~~~~~~~      ))
 \\     ~~~~~~      //
  --__--__--__--__--__
 --__--__--__--__--__
````

Comment: http://18.217.68.73/course/pages/java_1/assets/assignment01/duck.txt?date=JbSZDEwpVF -> here is a picture of the duck I should get to print 5 times

Answer (score 2):

The [Answer by Cosemuckel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76024600/642706) is correct. I can add some possible improvements.

## Soft-code each line-length

Firstly, the `ArrayList` could more compactly be replaced by [List.of](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E...)).

Or even better, use [text blocks](https://openjdk.org/jeps/378) for the duck. However the backslash characters must still be escaped. So I would “draw” my [ascii-art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art) in a simple [text-editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_editor) like [*TextEdit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextEdit) on macOS. Then paste into the Java editor of a smart [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) like [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) to create the text block while automatically adding escapes.

````java
final String duck =
        """
                      ____
                   __|____|__
                  |__________|
                   ((      ))
                  ((     O  ```)
                  ((        ``)
                   \\\\     x``
            (())    \\\\     X
           ((  ))~~~~      ))
         ((                 ))
        ((      ~~~~~~       ))
        ((     ~~~~~~~~      ))
         \\\\     ~~~~~~      //
          --__--__--__--__--__
         --__--__--__--__--__
        """;
````

To get lines from our duck string, use a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) of the lines collected into a `List`.

The main concept I suggest here is to  **[soft-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softcoding) the line length**. Let your code determine the longest line. Then, when printing the other lines, add a number of spaces to match that line length. You can multiply the SPACE character with a call to [`String#repeat`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)). Let the computer do the work!

We can replace the outer `for` loop with the simpler for-each syntax.

And we can better name our variables to be more [self-documenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code).

Lastly, account for a gap between each duck horizontally.

This code makes use of streams and method references, advanced features of Java. But those can be replaced with conventional loops and method calls, for those who are not yet familiar.

```java
final int countDucks = 5;
final List < String > lines = duck.lines().toList();
final OptionalInt maxLength = lines.stream().mapToInt( String :: length ).max();
final int gap = 7;
if ( maxLength.isPresent() )
{
    for ( String line : lines )
    {
        for ( int duckIndex = 0 ; duckIndex < countDucks ; duckIndex++ )
        {
            System.out.print( line + " ".repeat( maxLength.getAsInt() - line.length() + gap ) );
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

When run.

````
              ____                           ____                           ____                           ____                           ____             
           __|____|__                     __|____|__                     __|____|__                     __|____|__                     __|____|__          
          |__________|                   |__________|                   |__________|                   |__________|                   |__________|         
           ((      ))                     ((      ))                     ((      ))                     ((      ))                     ((      ))          
          ((     O  ```)                 ((     O  ```)                 ((     O  ```)                 ((     O  ```)                 ((     O  ```)       
          ((        ``)                  ((        ``)                  ((        ``)                  ((        ``)                  ((        ``)        
           \\     x``                     \\     x``                     \\     x``                     \\     x``                     \\     x``          
    (())    \\     X               (())    \\     X               (())    \\     X               (())    \\     X               (())    \\     X           
   ((  ))~~~~      ))             ((  ))~~~~      ))             ((  ))~~~~      ))             ((  ))~~~~      ))             ((  ))~~~~      ))          
 ((                 ))          ((                 ))          ((                 ))          ((                 ))          ((                 ))         
((      ~~~~~~       ))        ((      ~~~~~~       ))        ((      ~~~~~~       ))        ((      ~~~~~~       ))        ((      ~~~~~~       ))        
((     ~~~~~~~~      ))        ((     ~~~~~~~~      ))        ((     ~~~~~~~~      ))        ((     ~~~~~~~~      ))        ((     ~~~~~~~~      ))        
 \\     ~~~~~~      //          \\     ~~~~~~      //          \\     ~~~~~~      //          \\     ~~~~~~      //          \\     ~~~~~~      //         
  --__--__--__--__--__           --__--__--__--__--__           --__--__--__--__--__           --__--__--__--__--__           --__--__--__--__--__         
 --__--__--__--__--__           --__--__--__--__--__           --__--__--__--__--__           --__--__--__--__--__           --__--__--__--__--__
````

Answer (score 1):

## Same line length

When printing the ducks, **every line must have the same length**, currently some lines are longer than others.

Also note that lines using escape characters will need to appear longer in your editor!

Furthermore would it be practical to store all lines in an array and loop over that array, so that you don't need a for loop for every line!

Something like:

````java
import java.util.ArrayList; 
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numDucks = 5;

        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        lines.add("               ____           ");
        lines.add("            __|____|__        ");
        lines.add("           |__________|       ");
        lines.add("            ((      ))        ");
        lines.add("           ((     O  ```)\"    ");
        lines.add("           ((        ``)      ");
        lines.add("            \\\\     x``        ");
        lines.add("     (())    \\\\     X         ");
        lines.add("    ((  ))~~~~      ))        ");
        lines.add("  ((                 ))       ");
        lines.add(" ((      ~~~~~~       ))      ");
        lines.add(" ((     ~~~~~~~~      ))      ");
        lines.add("  \\\\     ~~~~~~      //       ");
        lines.add("   --__--__--__--__--__       ");
        lines.add("  --__--__--__--__--__        ");

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) { // for each line
            for (int j = 0; j < numDucks; j++) { // print it numDucks times
                System.out.print(lines.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
````

Comment: By the way, [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E...)) would simplify this code a bit.